# Tabledit Datepicker and Simple validation

Tags: php, ajax, validation, tabledit

Date picker for tabledit:

I have a php simple tabledit form with custom added insert button to create new entry that already work.
Because im not familiar with ajax that i want is simply to add a datepicker compatible with my tabledit

Data validation:

I think its critical to have validation,Not regex from client side  i think most effective is from server side.
I made a simple "if" for validate the 'first_name' its working but i want also to do this for 'add' not only for 'edit' and able to export error if not valid.

Look please my example of code if you have an working idea for datepicker and also for a validation technique, i dont know what is better validation to make it with ajax with php? pealse give me an example  for edit and for add procedure

index.php

```
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <title>How to use Tabledit plugin with jQuery Datatable in PHP Ajax</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/tabledit.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h3 align="center">How to use Tabledit plugin with jQuery Datatable in PHP Ajax</h3>
            <br />
            <div class="panel panel-default">
    
                <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
    
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="sample_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </body>
    
    </html>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    
            var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "order": [],
                "ajax": {
                    url: "fetch.php",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            });
    
            $('#sample_data').on('draw.dt', function() {
                $('#sample_data').Tabledit({
                    url: 'action.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    columns: {
                        identifier: [0, 'id'],
                        editable: [
                            [1, 'first_name'],
                            [2, 'last_name'],
                            [3, 'gender', '{"1":"Male","2":"Female"}']
                        ]
                    },
                    restoreButton: false,
                    onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (data.action == 'delete') {
                            $('#' + data.id).remove();
                            $('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
//////////insert data///////////
            $("#addRow").click(function() {
                var tableditTableName = '#sample_data'; // Identifier of table
                var newID = parseInt($(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("id")) + 1;
                var clone = $("table tr:last").clone();
                $(".tabledit-span", clone).text("");
                $(".tabledit-input", clone).val("");
                clone.prependTo("table");
                $(tableditTableName + " tbody tr:first").attr("id", newID);
                $(tableditTableName + " tbody tr:first td .tabledit-span.tabledit-identifier").text(newID);
                $(tableditTableName + " tbody tr:first td .tabledit-input.tabledit-identifier").val(newID);
                $(tableditTableName + " tbody tr:first td:last .tabledit-edit-button").trigger("click");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

action.php

```
<?php

//action.php

include('database_connection.php');

if ($_POST['action'] == 'edit') {

/////////simple validation///////////
    if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $valid = false;
        $errors['first_name'] = "name is required";
    } else {


        $data = array(
            ':first_name'  => $_POST['first_name'],
            ':last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
            ':sum'   => $_POST['sum'],
            ':gender'   => $_POST['gender'],
            ':id'    => $_POST['id']
        );

        $query = "
            UPDATE tbl_sample 
            SET first_name = :first_name, 
            last_name = :last_name, 
            sum = :sum, 
            gender = :gender 
            WHERE id = :id
            ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($data);
        echo json_encode($_POST);
    }
}

if ($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {
    $query = "
 DELETE FROM tbl_sample 
 WHERE id = '" . $_POST["id"] . "'
 ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

fetch.php

```
<?php

//fetch.php

include('database_connection.php');

$column = array("id", "first_name", "last_name", "sum", "gender");

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample ";

if (isset($_POST["search"]["value"])) {
    $query .= '
 WHERE first_name LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" 
 OR last_name LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" 
 OR gender LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" 
 ';
}

if (isset($_POST["order"])) {
    $query .= 'ORDER BY ' . $column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']] . ' ' . $_POST['order']['0']['dir'] . ' ';
} else {
    $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}
$query1 = '';

if ($_POST["length"] != -1) {
    $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$data = array();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row['id'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['first_name'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['last_name'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['gender'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['sum'];
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($connect)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
    'draw'   => intval($_POST['draw']),
    'recordsTotal' => count_all_data($connect),
    'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
    'data'   => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for _all_ your queries, not just some. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  If you mean the $("#addRow").click(function()  that adds data i cant find other way to integrate with the other ajax from tabletid.
For the other queries on action.php as i can see already have prepare statements

Comment: You have many places where you inject user data directly into the query instead of using placeholders. The only place you've used prepared statements correctly is in your UPDATE query. None of the other queries are using placeholders at all, which makes the call to `->prepare()` pointless and you wide open to SQL injections.